Make methods visible to a subfolder
My Rust project has a simple structure:
/src
  /stuff
    /mod.rs
    /foo.rs
  /stuff2
    /mod.rs
    /foo2.rs

Each mod.rs contains one line: pub mode foo; or pub mod foo2;
In foo.rs, I have:
pub struct Foo {}

impl Foo {
  fn private_method() {}
  pub fn public_method() {}
  pub fn visible_only_within_stuff_method() {}
}

How do I control the visibility of visible_only_within_stuff_method() so all other code inside /stuff can see it, but nothing outside it? I don't want it to be available to anything inside /stuff2.
What I'm looking for is the rough equivalent of package-private in Java.

You can make a member visible to the parent module with pub(super), so this should work:
pub(super) fn visible_only_within_stuff_method() {}

For deeply-nested members, you could instead name the stuff module directly:
pub(in crate::stuff) fn visible_only_within_stuff_method() {}

This may be preferable anyway to make the granted scope more explicit.

Further reading:

The Rust Reference - Visibility and privacy

